# can i recover my windows xp files after ubuntu install?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, partitioning

i installed ubuntu 10.04 on windows xp sp3, it used all the space in the of 320 gb in the hard drive. I had 200 gb data on hard disk on this hard disk under windows xp. is it all lost? 
can i get it back?

my system- 2 gb ram, 320 gb hard disk, intel core 2 duo processor
can give more details if there is any hope of recovery

best
Giri

Comment: There is a good chance to recover your data but **stop using the drive**: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/245987/data-recovery-after-replacing-windows-with-ubuntu or http://askubuntu.com/questions/94421/is-there-a-way-to-recover-files-from-a-storage-device-partially-overwritten-with

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

You can't recover the filesystem, but you can try to recover some files with:

- PhotoRec: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec
- ScalPel: http://www.digitalforensicssolutions.com/Scalpel

PS: Don't recover the files on the same disk!!!

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

The install of **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS** replaced (overwrote) the drive partition table, formatted the entire drive, and installed a new bootloader.

*There is **no** simple method of recovering your data, **and** many possible methods may irretrievably damage any forensic attempt to recover **any** of your data.*

This is when you realise you forgot:

- ***Always backup ALL user data, before attempting any major update or install.***

---

Only a **forensic recovery** tool, and skilled technician (as employed by police agencies), would be able to recover *some portion* of your data.

This would have a major cost associated.