# I accidentally formatted my hard disk containing ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, delete

I accidentally formatted my hard disk containing ubuntu partition. I also run a windows vista. I formatted my 2nd hdd, the ubuntu partition. after I reboot I'm getting a message

```
error:no such device:2fe5264c-df46-4507-9eee-8a7f1335c846
grub rescue>"
```

I also tried to boot from my liveCD by changing the bios menu.

I tried the following settings in the bios

- 1st boot   - cdrom \ usb
- 2nd boot   - hdd   \ cdrom \disabled
- 3rd boot   - usb   \ hdd   \disabled
  Still the same error is repeated. I also tried the following commands

  grub rescue> ls 
  (hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1) (fd0)
  grub rescue> ls (hd0)/boot 
  in all possible combinations

I get the error `error: unknown filesystem`

Except for the command `ls (fd0)\boot` I get `error : fd0 read error`. I totally formatted my 2nd hdd. My system is Desktop, P4, hdd1 80GiB (vista), hdd2 30GiB (ubuntu)(formatted) , 1GiB DDR RAM. now I cannot even load my Windows OS.

I also tried to install  windows 8 using USB and liveCD, but it didn't work. I can't even read my cd or usb drives.

Please someone help me.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, that it looks like your HDD is corrupt. You can obviously get to the Grub rescue prompt. When there, can you run the command `sudo fdisk -l /dev/fda` and let us know what the results are.

Answer (score 0):

In case we had not written to the accidentally formatted drive we are able to fully recover partitions with

- [TestDisk](https://askubuntu.com/a/246508/3940)