# How can I recover my data after formatting ubuntu with ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, data-recovery, testdisk

I blew up everything **while installing ubuntu 13.04 in a machine with ubuntu 12.04** installed in it. I erased the whole data accidentally. I had a separate space called `backup` in older OS.

Having **ubuntu 13.04** currently installed, I want my previous **data with ubuntu 12.04** back. I came through [How can I recover my data after replacing Windows with Ubuntu? [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/a/246508/37643), but in my case it's **ubuntu 13 replaced by ubuntu 12.**

In a **live mode of ubuntu 13.04**, I downloaded and run `testdisk`.

### STEP 1 : I proceeded with a media(`/dev/sda`) from list

```
Select a media (use Arrow keys, then press Enter):
>Disk /dev/sda - 640 GB / 596 GiB - WDC WD6400BEVT-22A0RT0
 Disk /dev/sdb - 4022 MB / 3835 MiB - SanDisk U3 Cruzer Micro
```

### STEP 2 : Then I selected `Intel` as partition and then **Analyse**  category

### STEP 3 : I only see following partitions

```
Disk /dev/sda - 640 GB / 596 GiB - CHS 77825 255 63
Current partition structure:
 Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

 1 * Linux                    0  32 33 77345  77 44 1242550272
 2 E extended             77345 110 12 77825  70  5    7708674
 5 L Linux Swap           77345 110 14 77825  70  5    7708672
```

### STEP 4 : I chose to go **Quick search**

```
Disk /dev/sda - 640 GB / 596 GiB - CHS 77825 255 63
 Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>* Linux                    0  32 33 77345  77 44 1242550272
 P Linux Swap           77345 110 14 77825  70  5    7708672
```

### STEP 5 : In first partition of the list (`Linux`), I only see currently installed files. (As 'm looking for older `backup` folder there.)

```
>drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 15-Mar-2014 23:59 .
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 15-Mar-2014 23:59 ..
 drwx------     0     0     16384 15-Mar-2014 23:55 lost+found
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0     12288 18-Mar-2014 22:59 etc
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 18-Mar-2014 22:41 media
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 16-Mar-2014 00:01 bin
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 16-Mar-2014 00:02 boot
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 24-Apr-2013 22:51 dev
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 15-Mar-2014 23:58 home
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 16-Mar-2014 00:01 lib
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 24-Apr-2013 22:47 lib64
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 19-Apr-2013 14:48 mnt
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 24-Apr-2013 22:46 opt
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 19-Apr-2013 14:48 proc
 drwx------     0     0      4096 16-Mar-2014 00:11 root
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 24-Apr-2013 22:51 run
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0     12288 16-Mar-2014 00:02 sbin
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 12-Jun-2012 00:21 selinux
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 24-Apr-2013 22:46 srv
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 30-Jan-2013 18:43 sys
 drwxrwxrwt     0     0      4096 18-Mar-2014 22:59 tmp
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 24-Apr-2013 22:46 usr
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 18-Mar-2014 22:59 var
 lrwxrwxrwx     0     0        29 15-Mar-2014 23:59 vmlinuz
 lrwxrwxrwx     0     0        33 15-Mar-2014 23:55 initrd.img.old
 lrwxrwxrwx     0     0        32 15-Mar-2014 23:59 initrd.img
 drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 15-Mar-2014 23:58 cdrom
```

### STEP 6 : In a Deeper search,

```
Analyse Cylinder 2041/77824 02%
Linux                    0  32 33 77345  77 44 1242550272
Linux                    0  32 31    60 206 16     974848
Linux                    0  32 31    60 206 16     974848
Linux                    0  32 31    60 206 16     974848
Linux                    0  32 33 77345  77 44 1242550272
Linux                    0  32 33 77345  77 44 1242550272
Linux                    0  32 33 77345  77 44 1242550272
Linux                    0  32 33 77345  77 44 1242550272
Linux                   60 238 51 12218 100 42  195309568
Linux                    0  32 33 77345  77 44 1242550272
Linux                   60 238 51 12218 100 42  195309568
Linux                   60 238 51 12218 100 42  195309568
Linux                    0  32 33 77345  77 44 1242550272
Linux                    0  32 33 77345  77 44 1242550272
Linux                   60 238 51 12218 100 42  195309568
Linux                   60 238 51 12218 100 42  195309568
Linux                    0  32 33 77345  77 44 1242550272
Linux                   60 238 51 12218 100 42  195309568
Linux                  854  98 13   924 127 35    1126400
Linux                    0  32 33 77345  77 44 1242550272
```

When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I get something like following in the list

```
Disk /dev/sda - 640 GB / 596 GiB - CHS 77825 255 63
Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>  Linux                    0  32 31    60 206 16     974848
Linux                    0  32 33 77345  77 44 1242550272
Linux                   60 238 51 12218 100 42  195309568
Linux                  854  98 13   924 127 35    1126400
Linux                 1596 214 27  1666 243 49    1126400
* Linux Swap           77345 110 14 77825  70  5    7708672
```

When I `list files` for the same partition, I get following message,

```
Linux                    0  32 31    60 206 16     974848
Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged.
```

I Want experienced answers.

#### References

[Test Disk - How to Recover Files from a Faulty Hard-Drive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Exq-aWBmRyI&list=PL868E3A52393FE8DE&index=12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, most of data is recovered properly using [R-studio](http://www.r-tt.com/data_recovery_linux/), a paid tool.

## How it works

[Why R-Studio](http://www.r-tt.com/Articles/Why_RStudio/index.shtml)

[R-Data Recovery Studio Guide: How To Recover Data](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEkVagcnBgA&list=PL868E3A52393FE8DE),  youtube video

Comment: Did you recover your old directory hierarchy and files correctly named ? Or a huge mess of files ?

Comment: @EdouardLopez Most of hierarchy was proper. But, say I had a folder `PorcupineTree` inside of `/backupPartition/Music/` in the beginning but moved to `/backupPartition/Music/Progressive` later, there were few such cases where I found `PorcupineTree` folder to be in `/backupPartition/Music` instead of where it recently was. Few cases were such that your folder name is `New folder`, means their earlier states. I think it dependes how much data have you moved around in your HardDisk.