# Ubuntu wiped the entire hard drive after selecting reinstall ubuntu option

Tags: data-recovery

Ubuntu just wiped the entire hard drive after selecting reinstall ubuntu option. I thought it would re-install in the same partition where ubuntu was previously installed. Now I don't know what to do, can I still recover my files on the other partition. If so, how? Please help I have some important files in there.

Comment: "Please help I have some important files in there." If files are important you make backups. Especially when messing with operating systems. Otherwise you can probably forget about those files. There is a tool called "testdisk" you might try.

Comment: Also this has a working solution it seems: http://askubuntu.com/questions/436031/how-can-i-recover-my-data-after-formatting-ubuntu-with-ubuntu?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The data recovery process of partial files requires a professional forensic support if the file is very important.
If the file is **not** very important (ex. it's not a bank code) you can try to use Open Source software like [PhotoRec Digital Picture and File Recovery](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) which is a friendly and unobtrusive alternative to TestDisk.
To start the RECOVERY procedure on your Linux system follow [the Official PhotoRec guide](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step#Run_PhotoRec_executable).
**Always make backups of your data before and after using any file recovery tool**.
**Every time you or the system write on the HD/SSD a deleted chunk of file may be overwritten; after 7 overwrites many files will not be recoverable without forensic support**.
NOTE: do not recover your files on the partition where you previously deleted them.
To backup your personal files use any application from the repository; to backup your system use professional Open Source tools like [Relax-and-Recover](http://relax-and-recover.org/). Do not make backups on USB media, use a DVD or a cloud-based system (I suggest [Ubuntu Cloud](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/ecosystem/ubuntu-public-cloud-programme) partners for an Open solution).