# Recovery of formatted hard drive!

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, format

**i had accidentally erase everything option while switching to ubuntu. can you please help me to tell me how recover that drive please as there are many important documents and photos. please if i can get your help..**

Comment: Did you have backups of the important stuff somewhere?

Comment: no i have not done so... :(

Comment: I rather think that it's a case of "it does what it says on the tin" and re-formats the drive irreversibly. In other environments, it might be possible to have the disk forensically examined to see if remnants of data are recoverable but that usually costs a considerable number of green drinking vouchers! A harsh lesson to learn unfortunately.

Comment: so no hopes to get my data back??

Comment: In a former life, we used to reformat Windows drives under Linux to be sure of completely destroying data before reformatting to be certain of cleaning up all the old stuff. So, basically, unless someone can say to the contrary, I think it's gone for ever. So, very sorry.

Comment: You could try looking at this earlier thread on the same subject:- http://askubuntu.com/questions/245987/how-can-i-recover-my-data-after-replacing-windows-with-ubuntu

Comment: thanks buddy.... as i am new to ubuntu i really need help... thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

There is an earlier thread which addresses this issue:- [How can I recover my data after replacing Windows with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245987/how-can-i-recover-my-data-after-replacing-windows-with-ubuntu)

First bit of advice in there is **"Stop using the drive!"**

Best of luck...

Comment: **Stop using the drive** is the most important piece of advice. All your files are lying around after a quick format, and all are recoverable if you don't overwrite those sectors. I accidentally formatted a key computer in my high school network (long story) and I had to research really hard to restore the data. I got off lightly, but I know the panic :P Keep at it.