# Is there any way to unformat an external hard drive?

Tags: data-recovery, external-hdd, format, recovery-mode

I accidentally formatted my external WD Elements hard disk.Is there any software to undo it.Or any way to just recover the photos in it.

Comment: It depends on how you formatted it in the first place. Please tell us more about that. The exact procedure you followed.

Comment: I used winsub to create a bootable windows from ubuntu, but accidentally used my external instead and it wiped out all my data on it.

Comment: It was a quick format,and I dont know if it helps but i cancelled it immediately though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recover a deleted NTFS partition with data](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171163/how-to-recover-a-deleted-ntfs-partition-with-data)

Comment: Another one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/245987/how-can-i-recover-my-data-after-replacing-windows-with-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at  `testdisk`. It should recover most of the data if the drive is formatted "quickly".

Comment: Its not detecting my hard disk "No hard disk found.You need to be root to use TestDisk"

Comment: run it as root with `sudo testdisk`