# Data recovery from SSD after reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: ssd, data-recovery

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my PC (on SSD-500GB). I did an update using `sudo apt update` and rebooted the system. But when I tried to log in again I got stuck in a login loop and got a black screen. I did everything possible to remove that error (even purged the nvidia drivers) but failed.

So without any backup of my data I tried reinstalling Ubuntu from USB. I didn't format or delete anything. Now I can log in, but I've lost all my data which was on the PC's SSD. Is there any way to recover the data? Any software I can use to do that? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Next time, use the installer's "Try Ubuntu" environment to carefully back up your data to a safe media before installing or re-installing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attempt a data recovery, **you should immediately stop using the system**.

What you should do is boot from a live cd with your disks unmounted and run a data recovery tool. It will require you to plug in an external HDD of at least the same capacity as your drive. It will probably run for hours, and will generate thousands of garbage files which you will have to check by hand.

There are several similar questions (although they overwrote their data with a Windows installation, it is the same problem) that have data recovery tools recommendations [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245987/how-can-i-recover-my-data-after-replacing-windows-with-ubuntu) and [and this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu) such as [testdisk](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/testdisk) (which I've never used) but you may need to look for tools tailored for SSDs.